# NetManager crashes on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, server, desktop-environments, 23.10, proxmox

I have tried 23.10 server and desktop but after a few minutes I lose network connectivity.
Both were VMs on Proxmox 8.1.3. I am using VirtIO(paravirtualized), first on a Realtek NIC, then on an Intel i930. Netmanager (Desktop) crashed and I lose all setting for either NIC and I can no longer set them up. I try with ip and ifconfig (Desktop and Server) and see that they lost their IP information and carrier type. What logs do I need to get? I have a VM template before this happens so I can start fresh for new logs if needed.

Comment: I suspect that the various versions of "Netmanager" refers to NetworkManager. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop and 23.10 Server use different networking services, so the same problem on both would suggest that neither NetworkManager (desktop) nor networkd (server) are the culprit.

Comment: Similar issues on both, but with Desktop I get a crashed Netmanager application.

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. To improve your question and add more information, please edit instead.